# Convert JSON to a single line String and vice versa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I want to convert a JSON into a string field to save into database and again convert it back to JSON.

Ex. below is structure of JSON:

```
{
"students":[{
"name": "Albert",
"code":"GE",
"marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},
{
"name": "Gert",
"code":"LE",
"marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},
{
"name": "John"
},
{
"name": "John Doe",
"code":"LP",
"marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}
]
}
```

I want to convert this into a String field, "storedInput", so that i can save it into database, ideally saving only the JSON data.
I also want to convert it back to the JSON when I send it back to the user.

Below is the conversion strategy I used to convert it into delimited String.

"Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John-$-$#Johnah Doe-LP-40"

But I dont think its the best strategy as it gets extremely complicated to convert it back.

```
public String convertStudentList(List<Student> studentList) {
    return studentList.stream().map(this::mapStudent).collect(Collectors.joining("#"));
}

public String checkData(String data) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(data).isPresent() ? data : "$";
}

public String mapStudent(Student student) {
    List<Marks> marks = student.getMarks();
    if (marks != null) {
        String mark = marks.stream().map(m -> m.getMark()).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
        return checkData(student.getName()) + "-" + checkData(student.getCode()) + "-" + mark;
    } else {
        return checkData(student.getName()) + "-" + checkData(student.getCode()) + "-" + "$";
    }
}
```

Edit:

1. I do not have access to make any changes to the table structure.
2. I cannot simply store the entire JSON, ex. using Jackson Object Mapper, as there are space constraints, ideally i just want to store the value and convert it back.

Comment: What have you tried, please share your code?

Comment: Can't you just strip out all the line feeds and/or carriage returns?  Then it will be both JSON AND a single line String.

Comment: The backend does not want me to maintain a JSON structure. My Strategy was to store it as a delimitted String ex. NAME-CODE-MARK&MARK# ex. "Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John-$-$#Johnah Doe-LP-40". But this is making it extremely difficult for me to convert it back efficiently. I will add my main conversion strategy methods, by editing the questions. But do not know whether how much that would be helpful as not sure if I am following the best approach itself.

Comment: Have you tried using [Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) it is pretty convenient you can parse back and forth from String to JSON with it

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't storing the students individually in your database with their fields as columns?

Comment: I do not own the database, so there is no option of making changes to the table structure. I am just piggybacking on one of the fields to store my data. Same reason I cant simply use Jackson, since it will convert it directly into JSON with the " and variable Names also, ideally I just want to store the data, and convert it back to JSON at my end as I do have access to the JSONObject Structure. There is restriction in the number of characters the database field can hold, so trying to eliminate characters wherever possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "I just want to store the data"? Also, what do you mean by "I want to convert a JSON into a string field to save into database" If you already have JSON it is already a string by definition. If what you have isn't a string, then it isn't JSON. If you have a a `List<Student>` then you should use Jackson or GSON to convert your `List` to a JSON string. Otherwise, you will either have to write your own JSON serializer or invent your own format, both of which will take a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

**Using JDK 15**

> **Text Blocks** : Text blocks start with a “”” (three double-quote marks) followed by optional whitespaces and a newline.

Please find the solution below to convert json to string and vice-versa, it might help you in some way.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String s = """
        {
        "students":[{
        "name": "Albert",
        "code":"GE",
        "marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},
        {
        "name": "Gert",
        "code":"LE",
        "marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},
        {
        "name": "John"
        },
        {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "code":"LP",
        "marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}
        ]
        }
        """;
    //JSON TO STRING
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String s2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(s);
    System.out.println("JSON TO STRING:" + s2);

    //STRING TO JSON
    String s3 = mapper.readValue(s2, new TypeReference<>() {});
    System.out.println("STRING TO JSON:" + s3);

  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 JSON TO STRING:"{\n\"students\":[{\n\"name\": \"Albert\",\n\"code\":\"GE\",\n\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"20\"},{\"mark\":\"40\"}]},\n{\n\"name\": \"Gert\",\n\"code\":\"LE\",\n\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"26\"}]},\n{\n\"name\": \"John\"\n},\n{\n\"name\": \"John Doe\",\n\"code\":\"LP\",\n\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"40\"}]}\n]\n}\n"
    STRING TO JSON:{
    "students":[{
    "name": "Albert",
    "code":"GE",
    "marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},
    {
    "name": "Gert",
    "code":"LE",
    "marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},
    {
    "name": "John"
    },
    {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "code":"LP",
    "marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, due to Space constraints I can't simply store the entire JSON with the VariableNames, { , ". Neither could have used Jasckson.

Comment: okay, May you please elaborate a bit more like in what are the values from json object that you want to store in the database in form of string?

Comment: My Strategy was to store it in this way: "Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John-$-$#Johnah Doe-LP-40", Albert GE 20 40 ... all are the values I want to store. But am not sure what the best strategy would be and how to go about encoding and decoding it back.

Comment: okay, let me try with this formatting.

Comment: @kselvan9000 I have added one more solution below, i hope this will solve your query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you store the students in a table with a column for each attribute from the JSON. I am not familiar with Spring, but other web frameworks I used are able to fetch a row from the database and seralize it to JSON in the way you want. They can also take JSON and put it into the database as individual columns rather than an single string.

Comment: Yes ideally this would be the best option, but I do not have the liberty to make any changes to the existing table structure. I am just piggybacking in one on the fields to store my data.

Answer (score 0):

Library *Josson* has the capability.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

Encode

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "\"students\":[{" +
    "\"name\": \"Albert\"," +
    "\"code\":\"GE\"," +
    "\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"20\"},{\"mark\":\"40\"}]}," +
    "{" +
    "\"name\": \"Gert\"," +
    "\"code\":\"LE\"," +
    "\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"26\"}]}," +
    "{" +
    "\"name\": \"John\"" +
    "}," +
    "{" +
    "\"name\": \"John Doe\"," +
    "\"code\":\"LP\"," +
    "\"marks\":[{\"mark\":\"40\"}]}" +
    "]" +
    "}");
JsonNode encoded = josson.getNode(
    "students@.concatFree(name,'-',code,'-',marks.mark.join('&')).@join('#')");
System.out.println(encoded.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
"Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John--#John Doe-LP-40"
```

Decode

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "\"Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John--#Johnah Doe-LP-40\"");
JsonNode decoded = josson.getNode(
    "split('#').split('-').map(name:[0],code:[1],marks:[2].split('&').map(mark:?)).toObject('students')");
System.out.println(decoded.toPrettyString());
```

Output

```
{
  "students" : [ {
    "name" : "Albert",
    "code" : "GE",
    "marks" : [ {
      "mark" : "20"
    }, {
      "mark" : "40"
    } ]
  }, {
    "name" : "Gert",
    "code" : "LE",
    "marks" : [ {
      "mark" : "26"
    } ]
  }, {
    "name" : "John"
  }, {
    "name" : "Johnah Doe",
    "code" : "LP",
    "marks" : [ {
      "mark" : "40"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using JDK 17:**

***I have implemented the below code using some of the latest java features apart from Java 8.***

> **Records in java 14 :** As of JDK 14, we can replace our data classes
> with records. Records are immutable classes that require only the type
> and name of fields. We do not need to create constructor, getters,
> setters, override toString() methods, override hashcode and equals
> methods.

> **Text Blocks in java 15:** Text blocks start with a “”” (three double-quote marks)
> followed by optional whitespaces and a newline.

The below code will give you the pattern that you want to store in the database in the form of a string. I hope this will solve your query.

```
public class JsonTest {
          public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
            
            //Converting json to formatted String
            record Marks(String mark){}
            record Student(String name, String code, List<Marks> marks){}
            record Response(List<Student> students){}
        
            String input = """
                     {
                               "students":[{
                               "name": "Albert",
                               "code":"GE",
                               "marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},
                               {
                               "name": "Gert",
                               "code":"LE",
                               "marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},
                               {
                               "name": "John"
                               },
                               {
                               "name": "John Doe",
                               "code":"LP",
                               "marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}
                               ]
                               }
                """;
        
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Response studentData = mapper.readValue(input, new TypeReference<>() {});
        
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
            studentData.students().forEach(x -> {
              sb.append(x.name() + "-");
              sb.append(x.code()!= null ? x.code() : "$");
              sb.append("-");
              sb.append(x.marks()!= null ? x.marks().stream().filter(y -> y.mark()!=null).map(Marks::mark).collect(Collectors.joining("&")) : "$");
              sb.append("#");
            });
            
            System.out.println(sb);
          }
    
    //Converting formatted String to original json
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.asList(sb.toString().split("#")).forEach(student -> {
    
          String[] splitArr1 = student.split("-");
          String[] splitArr2 = splitArr1[2].split("&");
    
          String name = splitArr1[0];
          String code = splitArr1[1].contains("$")?null:splitArr1[1];
          List<Marks> marks = Arrays.stream(splitArr2).filter(y -> !y.contains("$")).map(Marks::new).toList();
    
          Student s = new Student(name,code,marks);
          students.add(s);
        });
        Response out = new Response(students);
    
        String backToJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(out);
    
        System.out.println(backToJson);
    }
        }
```

**Output:**

```
//Converting json to formatted String
 Albert-GE-20&40#Gert-LE-26#John-$-$#John Doe-LP-40#
//Converting formatted String to original json
{"students":[{"name":"Albert","code":"GE","marks":[{"mark":"20"},{"mark":"40"}]},{"name":"Gert","code":"LE","marks":[{"mark":"26"}]},{"name":"John","code":null,"marks":[]},{"name":"John Doe","code":"LP","marks":[{"mark":"40"}]}]}
```

Comment: @kselvan9000 you can try this approach, i hope this is what you have asked for.